# Getting the error unexpected "{"

Tags: php

I am kind of embarraced asking this, but i keep getting the error unexpected "{"

```
<?php
$c = trim($_POST['cm']);
$inc = trim($_POST['inches']);
$resultat;

if (isset($c)) && (isset($inc)){
echo "string";
exit();
}

if(isset($c)){
echo "string";
exit();
}

if(isset($inc)){
echo "string";
exit();
}
?>
```

Im testing if both variables are empty, then im testing if one of them is empty ...
but i keep getting a syntax error under every if statement ... cant see what i missed?

Comment: Look at the brackets on the first if.

Comment: I don't know where to start.

Comment: Surely the error message gave you a line number? You open a bracket, you close a bracket.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (isset($c)) && (isset($inc)){
```

should be

```
if (isset($c) && isset($inc)){
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one more bracket in if...

```
if ((isset($c)) && (isset($inc)){
    echo "string";
    exit();
}
```